# Re-throwing error from Observable.catch in AuthGuard canActivate

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the following code in AuthGuard's `canActivate` method:

```js
return this.http.get(url)
  .map(res => {
    console.log(res.json());
    return true;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return Observable.throw(error);
    // return Observable.of(false);
  });
```

When I uncomment the `Observable.of(false)` line, all is well. However, I want to not only return false wrapped in an Observable, I also want to re-throw the error so that my global custom `ErrorHandler` would catch it and display a user-friendly message.

Comment: No can do. `CanActivate` has an interface of `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean` Anything else is a compile error and that is because the code that "consumes" the method expects a logical value only.

Comment: What you "can" do is wire into another service and include logic to send the error there. Then you can handle that error either within the service logic or similarly expose an observable for something to consume and react to the data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following. Would that also be in the `catch` function?

Comment: How about chaining another operator after `catch` by the way?

Comment: Then you need to inject ErrorHandler into the guard and trigger an error there before returning a boolean from canActivate. I guess this is what previous comment says. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be helpful if you're not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Observable.throw('error')
    .catch(error => {
        return Observable.throw(error).startWith(false);
    })
    .subscribe(
        value => console.log('Next', value),
        err => console.log('Error', err)
    );
```

The Observable returned from `catch()` is just a regular Observable that can throw errors as well.

Note that you have to set the error callback in `subscribe()` otherwise the error would be re-thrown.

This demo prints the following output:

```
Next: false
Error: error
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I do that without subscribing at all? I'm asking since I'm returning Observer<boolean> to canActivate in the first place.

Comment: You need to subscribe somewhere, I guess canActivate subscribes itself but I've never used it myself so I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

`canActivate` works in conjuction with the `Router.navigate` method (amongst others). These methods returns the results of canActivate by Promise, therefore the way to handle canActivate errors are to handle it in the Promise. I've found the best way to highlight errors at the callsite is to use rxjs/throwError as result of the canActivate:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    if (!someError) {
      throwError(`The raeson`)
    }
    return true;
  }
```

... and the navigation promise:

```
this.router.navigate([...segments]).catch(reason => {
  console.error(`Could not navigate ...: ${reason}`);
});
```

NOTE: The navigation expects canActivate to return an observable that completes (which throwError does, exposing the error to the promise).